# Placement new and alignment in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following code snippet constructing an instance of a POD (plain old data) struct in-place:

```
#include <new>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstddef>

struct Test
{
    int a;
    char b;
    double c;
};

int main()
{
    const std::size_t minimumNumberOfBytes = sizeof( Test ) * 4;

    // Get a block of memory that can accommodate a Test instance and then some!
    void* const ptrToMemBlock = new char[ minimumNumberOfBytes ];
    assert( ptrToMemBlock );

    // Construct a Test instance in-place.
    const Test* const testInstance( ::new ( ptrToMemBlock ) Test() );

    // Is this assumption guaranteed to be true?
    assert( testInstance == ptrToMemBlock );
}
```

Is the assumption represented by the final assert() **guaranteed** to always be correct? Or is it conceivable that the compiler might decide to construct the Test instance, say a few bytes after the start of the memory block I specified in the placement-new call?

Note that I'm asking specifically about POD types here. I know that things can get iffy if multiple inheritance and stuff like that gets involved.

Comment: malloc returns pointer aligned for any data type. Don't know about new. Ps don't forget to delete it.

Comment: Non-array placement `new` never puts the object anywhere other than at the address you give it. Providing a suitably aligned address is *your* responsibility.

Comment: Hmm, now that I've thought about it, the compiler would have to construct the Test instance exactly at the start of the specified memory block, because if it decided to construct it with an offset from the the start of the memory block then specifying a block of sizeof( Test ) bytes might not suffice in some cases.

Comment: @antred Yes your last comment is pretty much the gist of it.

Comment: @Kerrek SB But actually providing that suitably aligned address is optional unless I'm on an architecture that doesn't take kindly to misaligned memory accesses, right? I mean in a normal Windows application, the worst case scenario would be that I suffer a performance loss. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @antred by "normal Windows application" you mean "program running on X86 etc" (since this is a processor issue, not an OS issue) and the worst-case scenario is that the object contains 128-bit SSE2 vector types, which may be accessed using instructions that require 16-byte alignment. Windows also runs on ARM which may have its own issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the assertion will hold. Any `new` expression creating a single object must request exactly `sizeof(Test)` bytes of storage from the allocation function; and so it must place the object at the start of that storage in order to have enough room.

*Note*: This is based on the specification of a *new-expression* in C++11. It looks like C++14 will change the wording, so the answer may be different in the future.

Comment: Is it really true that new will give you EXACTLY the number of requested bytes? I was under the impression that it would give you AT LEAST the requested number of bytes.

Comment: @antred: No, there's nothing to stop over-allocating. But when a `new` expression calls `operator new` to allocate memory, it must request exactly the amount it needs; and so it must assume that it has no more than that.

Comment: @antred: new may over allocate, but there's no way to tell, so you must always assume that it gave you the exact amount.

Comment: Since new `char[N]` is only guaranteed to provide at least `N` characters, accessing indices `> N - 1` is going to be undefined.  So to all intents and purposes it gives you only exactly what you asked for.

Comment: @Mooing Duck That's a very good point and kind of moots my initial comment.

Comment: Actually, it may request more!

Comment: @Deduplicator: Not for a single object. "it may be
greater than the size of the object being created **only if the object is an array**"

Comment: Or the allocation is extended.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I've no idea what you mean. My quote came directly from C++11 5.3.4/10, and has no other exceptions. For a single object, the `new` expression can't request more than the object size.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: See 5.3.4 [expr.new] §§ 10. It starts "An implementation is allowed to omit a call to a replaceable global allocation function..."

Comment: @Deduplicator: OK, it looks like the answer will be more complicated in C++14. I'll mention that I'm referring to C++11, which doesn't say anything like that.

Comment: @Mike Seymour Oh great, _more_ complexity is just what C++ needed! ;-)

Answer (score 12):

This assertion will always hold, because `new` is required to return blocks of memory with MAXIMUM possible alignment. BTW - your first `assert()` is worthless, as normal `new` does not return `nullptr` - it throws or aborts, only "nothrow `new`" can return `nullptr`.

Comment: True. I am aware that new will always either return a pointer to memory or just throw. I just put the assert in to rule out answers like "Well no, because it's not guaranteed that your code even reaches the final assert."

Comment: While this answer is not wrong, I think it misses the point of the question.

Comment: Actually, the answer is probably also just wrong. The maximal-alignment guarantee is only for `new char[N]`, not for general types.

Comment: @KerrekSB: He is using `new char[N]`, but technically the guarantee is for the largest alignment of the primitives.  Larger alignments could also occur in theory, but neither `new` nor `malloc` will align for them.

Comment: @MooingDuck: The point is that the result of `new T[N]` may not be aligned for `U`, where as `new char[N]` is always suitably aligned. Cf. [expr.new]/11.

Comment: @KerrekSB: And there is no such guarantee for placemen-new anyway.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the the last `assert` is guaranteed to hold, because this form of placement-new must always return the passed pointer, not using any space for itself:

> #### 5.3.4 New `[expr.new]`
>
> 8 A *new-expression* may obtain storage for the object by calling an *allocation function* (3.7.4.1). [...]
>   10 An implementation is allowed to omit a call to a replaceable global *allocation function* (18.6.1.1, 18.6.1.2). When it does so, the storage is instead provided by the implementation or provided by extending the allocation of another *new-expression*. [...]
>   11 When a new-expression calls an allocation function and **that allocation has not been extended**, the newexpression passes the amount of space requested to the allocation function as the first argument of type `std::size_t`. **That argument shall be no less than the size of the object being created; it may be greater than the size of the object being created only if the object is an array.**
>   [...]

Your new-expression calls the global placement-new allocation-function.
That is a non-replacable function, thus the allocation cannot be extended or omitted.
Also, you are not allocating an array but a single object, thus no padding of the request may occur at all.

> #### 18.6.1.3 Placement forms `[new.delete.placement]`
>
> 1 These functions are reserved, a C++ program may not define functions that displace the versions in the Standard C++ library (17.6.4). The provisions of (3.7.4) do not apply to these reserved placement forms of `operator new` and `operator delete`.
>
> ```
> void* operator new(std::size_t size, void* ptr) noexcept;
> ```
>
> 2 Returns: `ptr`.
>   3 Remarks: Intentionally performs no other action.

And this guarantees that the allocation-function returns the passed pointer unchanged.

Comment: Kudos for citing the standard! :-) What does it mean for an allocation to be "extended", though?

Comment: @antred: Added some more quotes and explanations. Now it's proven.